Automation script not finding elements
I am learning automation with Selenium WebDriver and python. Some of my scripts are not able to find elements even though I clearly depict where it is, for example for Barnes and Noble website I search for the search bar using class name:
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(7)
search_bar = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'rbt-input-main form-control rbt-input user-success')

but it is unable to find it. Another example is when I search for something with a full XPath:
self.fifty_xpath="/html/body/div/div[3]/form/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/span/div/div[3]/label/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div"
self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, self.fifty_xpath).click()

When I follow along to tutorials it is fine I just have trouble when I create my own code.
I tried finding with multiple sources (id, name, XPath) and also tried different sections to see which can be clicked. The main and only problem is it cannot find the element from the CSS selector.

The problem with your class name locator
(By.CLASS_NAME,'rbt-input-main form-control rbt-input user-success')

is that By.CLASS_NAME is expecting a single class name and you've passed it 4. If you actually need more than one class to locate that element successfully, then you should convert it to a CSS selector.
(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'.rbt-input-main.form-control.rbt-input.user-success')

For your XPath, absolute XPaths (ones that start from /html), long XPaths (lots of levels), ones that use indices (/div[3], etc.) are very brittle and should be avoided. The ideal is that you learn how to craft your own locator instead of copying them out of the browser or some other locator creation tool.
The search box on the site can be located simply with a CSS selector,
(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[placeholder='Search by Title, Author, Keyword or ISBN']")

I'm not sure what your XPath was trying to locate. I checked it all the way up to the /form and it was all missing. I'm assuming it's from another page or something. You'll need to provide more info if you want help with that element.

Thank you so much! I will definitely try these out!

And yes, the other link was an example from another page. I did not necessarily need help for the page itself (because it was my own)
